# How to create a bar chart in D3?

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I need help creating a bar chart, just a normal bar chart.

I have 5 objects, each with their own 10 fields. I want to create a side-by-side bar layout where the x axis labels are the 10 fields. Above the ith field should be a rectangle for each 5 object with each height corresponding to that objects data for that field. Each object has its own distinctive color.

I've spend 4+ hours and I've got nothing. Google reveals nothing that helps. Note: the rectangles of the bar chart should be vertical.

Edit: I'm not getting a lot of help. The answers have been unhelpful, though no fault of the authors. So here's my situation. I'm reading a JSON. The format of the JSON

```
 [  
   ...
   {
     "RowID":85,
     "Name":"Tormore",
     "B":2,
     "S":2,
     "S2":1,
     "M":0,
     "T":"0",
     "H":1,
     "S":0,
     "W":1,
     "N":2,
     "Malty":1,
     "Fruity":0,
     "Floral":0
 }

 ...
 ]
```

There are a total of 86 JSON pieces of data. That is, there 86 RowID's. I need to only work with 5. There needs to be 5 colors or however many rowID's I want to work with. The x-axis are the "B", "S" ... "Floral" from the JSON. So there should be "clumps" of 5 bars (colored corresponding to "Name") for each "B", ... "Floral" piece of data. The end goal is to make it easy for the user to visually compare 5 things according to their attributes.

I cannot make this work with the given examples. I've been working on this for at least 6 hours. I'm at my wits end.

Comment: See http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/

Comment: It sounds like you want a stacked bar chart.  After reading the tutorials linked by @CarlManaster, check out [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768).  Or read [this chapter of Stuart Murray's book](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch11.html#_stack_layout) for a more step-by-step introduction.  You may need to change some of the data-manipulation code to work with your data; most stacked bar graphs have each stack in a separate object, with the layers as properties, instead of having each layer in a separate object, with the x-values as properties.

Comment: Ah, I read again and I see you want a grouped bar chart, not stacked.  But there are lots of examples of those too, including the one @FernOfTheAndes adapted.  You just need to know what to call it so that you can search for it!  A good source is the [gallery on the d3 wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery), or Christophe Viau's [Big D3 Example List gallery](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery).  Then you can figure out the name of what you want by looking at the pictures!

Answer (score 1):

It is tough to interpret questions at times...I thought the user might want a grouped bar chart :-) Anyways, I borrowed this [graph](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051) from Mike and cooked up this [UPDATED fiddle with appropriate variable names](http://jsfiddle.net/zLmUK/3/). If that is what you want, you can add more fields and objects and, of course, change the values appropriately. (The color scale may have to be touched as well.)

Some of the fake data:

```
var data = [
    {"Field":"Field1","Object1":"2704659","Object2":"4499890"},
    {"Field":"Field2","Object1":"2027307","Object2":"3277946"},
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand what this is doing: var ageNames = d3.keys(data[1]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Field"; });

Comment: Remove the filter and see what happens...I suggest playing around with it and understanding the way the graph is being built.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that I borrowed the graph and did not spend time changing variable names, etc. Perhaps in the end this turned out to be more confusing than clarifying, which was definitely not my intent. So, if this is indeed the graph you had in mind, I suggest that you compare the code with Mike's and see the changes I made. That should help.

Comment: @lars Update the fiddle with appropriate variable names. Hope this helps.

Comment: I would down vote this answer if I could. It's completely useless for what I want and the author doesn't even seem to understand it. If you are going to post code, it's a pretty good idea to understand it.

Comment: @lars Thanks for adding more information to your question.  But that's not an excuse for ragging on someone who spent time trying to help you.  Especially when the answer is almost perfect, you just have to make one last connection.  FernOfTheAndes' example has your data-structure inside out, yes.  But all it takes is a few lines of code to make your data structure match, and then you can use the rest of the code.  Yes, you *could* graph your data the way you want without doing so, but then you'd have to change the rest of the code.  And you've spent hours and hours without figuring it out...

Comment: So instead of banging your head against the wall, look at the code examples you have, and figure out how you can make your data suit them.  Here's one approach to take, you will have to adapt it a bit for your data to only use the relevant fields: http://jsfiddle.net/zLmUK/4/

Comment: @AmeliaBR I tried your code. I tried adapting it. It simply does not work. This is not a matter of merely changing some fields. Any more ideas?

Comment: @lars why don't you post *your* code as an edit to the question, and ideally also create a working fiddle (working meaning that the data is being parsed successfully, scales set up and so on, even if you haven't got the layout right).  Then we can help figure out where you're going wrong.  We're giving you working examples, but we can't read your mind.

Comment: @AmeliaBR Oh, I have. And the answers have not been helpful.