# Creating a bar chart in D3 from subset of json data. Xaxis is ordinal

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, bar-chart

```
 [  
   ...
   {

     "RowID":85,
     "Name":"Billy",
     "B":2,
     "S":2,
     "S2":1,
     "M":0,
     "T":"0",
     "H":1,
     "S":0,
     "W":1,
     "N":2,
     "Malty":1,
     "Fruity":0,
     "Floral":0
 }

 ...
 ]
```

I need to create a bar chart. Just a regular bar chart.

There are a total of 86 JSON pieces of data (that is, you'll find 86 RowIDs). I only need to pick 5-10 that I want to work with. The x-axis are the "B", "S" ... "Floral" from the JSON. It does NOT include RowID or Name. So there should be "clumps" of 5 bars (colored corresponding to "Name") for each "B", ... "Floral" piece of data. The end goal is to make it easy for the user to visually compare 5 objects (distinguished by Name attribute) according to their attributes.

I've been working at least 24 hours on this problem. And I'm not making any progress. I've looked at tutorials and other posts on StackOverflow. I can't get any of them to work.

Anyone?

And no, this question does not have an answer somewhere else.

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zdy6d/3/

Comment: Please do not ask two very similar questions a few hours apart.  Edit the main question so that all the answers, comments, and replies from you are in the same place.  Also, fiddles are only useful if you take the time to make them functional for everything except the one area that you're having problems with.  Otherwise, you might as well just dump your code here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a bar chart in D3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790119/how-to-create-a-bar-chart-in-d3)

Comment: well, i tried to delete it. and then i flagged it to be closed because it wouldn't let me delete it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is a [grouped bar chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051). The main thing you need to do is create 2 x-scales: one that gives the position of each group, or clump as you call it, in the screen and the other one that gives the position of each series (name in this case) inside the group.

```
// Where to position each clump inside svg chart
var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal();
x0.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== 'RowID' && key !== 'Name'; }));
x0.rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);

// Where to position each name bar inside the clump
var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();
x1.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Name; } ));
x1.rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
```

You then have to filter the data and maybe change its structure to a more convenient format (e.g. `[{groupname: 'B', data: [{name: 'Bobby', value: 3}, {name: 'Tom', value: 5}, ... ]}, ...]` should be similar to the one the example I linked uses)

Minimal working JSFiddle with example of data manipulation and rect creation: http://jsfiddle.net/LeartS/23huy/2/

Comment: It's still not working and the line "x0.rangeBoundBands([0, width], 0.1);" is giving the error "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'x0.rangeBoundBands([0, width], 0.1)')". Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/zdy6d/

Comment: There was an error in my code, sorry (Javascript `in` is not as cool as Python `in`), edited. I also added a little more information. If you're having problem with the data manipulation I can give some indications on that later, at the moment I'm typing from my smartphone.

Comment: So I've been looking at this example for the past couple of days. I don't know how to get it to work for me. I have 86 "things" and I need 5. And I'm not sure what you mean or how to get the data into a more convenient format.

Comment: Yeah, this still doesn't work. I can't get the data out for the legend, and the boxes are all weird looking.

Comment: There are way too many things that are undefined when I run the program.

Comment: this is a completely unhelpful answer and I would downvote if I could.

Comment: I just now realized that you must not have even read my question!

Comment: Wow, I took the time to write you a completely functional fiddle (except for the different coloring of the bars, at least that you could do on your own..) and you complain with random comments ('the boxes are weird looking'?) and say I haven't even read your question. Amazing. My fiddle starts from data formatted exactly as yours and creates a clump of bars for each feature (A, B, floreal..) , and in each clump there is exactly a bar for each name. How is that different from your explanation? Again, amazing.

Comment: Wow, LeartS. You took the time to give me something that is completely functional but not related to my question. So that is why I consider this answer a complete waste of time.

Comment: Than maybe you should rewrite your question. It seems to me my fiddle does what you want, particularly: " So there should be "clumps" of 5 bars (colored corresponding to "Name") for each "B", ... "Floral" piece of data. The end goal is to make it easy for the user to visually compare 5 objects (distinguished by Name attribute) according to their attributes." it's exactly what my fiddle does. (not 5 but 2,but you are not talking about that, are you?)

Comment: I admit that it could be clearer ("the distinguished by Name attribute" part). But the I want "clumps" of 5 bars for each key. That part is clear. However, your fiddle does nothing to answer this. (What I wanted was for the x-axis to have the key attributes, the data for each attribute was to be colored according to name.)